# POST multiple issues to redmine via API

Tags: api, post, curl, batch-file, redmine

Complete Noob to curl, REST APIs and redmine stuck on something that might be quite simple but I cannot find an answer to it despite trawling the forums for a long time...

I have been trying to batch import multiple issues to Redmine without success.

I am now experimenting with the REST api using curl. I can post issues individually but cannot figure out how I can POST many issues at the same time? I assume that this is a common problem faced by people importing lots of stuff to redmine...

this is the curl command I am using:

```
curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data "@test2.json" \
  -u user:password localhost/redmine/issues.json
```

and this is the test2.json file:

```javascript
{
    "issue": {
    "project_id": 9,
    "subject": "TEST5",
    "notes": "foobar",
    "priority_id": 2
    },

    "issue": {
    "project_id": 9,
    "subject": "TEST6",
    "notes": "barfoo",
    "priority_id": 3
    }    
}
```

Currently it only picks up the second issue... Can anybody suggest what I may be doing wrong or a better alternative?

#### Environment

Bitnami Redmine stack on Windows 7

```
Redmine version                          2.3.0.stable
Ruby version                             1.9.3 (i386-mingw32)
Rails version                            3.2.13
Environment                              production
Database adapter                         Mysql2
```

Comment: If you try to add more than 2 issues, are all imported except the first one? or in that case also only the second one is added?

Comment: Sorry for the late response.  Only the second issue is added. I am now having the same problem trying to import projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the easiest solution for importing external data here:

http://www.redmine.org/boards/1/topics/37725?r=38232

This allows import direct from csv which works out perfectly for me!

Comment: It might solve your problem, but it doesn't answer your question.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the python module called [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/). It'll help you open URLs so you can POST and GET information from Redmine. This is what I used to push data to my local Redmine server.

For example, you can POST users to Redmine via this format:

```
username = 'admin'
password = 'admin'
url = 'http://localhost:3000/users.json'

payload = {
        'user': {
            'login': login,
            'password': password,
            'firstname': firstname,
            'lastname': lastname,
            'mail': mail
        }
    }

parameters_json = json.dumps(payload)
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
r = requests.post(url, auth=(username, password), data=parameters_json, headers=headers)
```

So instead of users, POST to issues via: localhost:3000/issues.json

And follow Redmine's [RESTful API guide](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_Issues), so that you're entering the right parameters.

Comment: I am struggling...lost in a world of pip, easy_install, distribute. Surely installing a module should be easier than this...

Comment: No problem. I can walk you through. I use Mac for development as it's just really easy, but it seems you're using Windows? I would consider downloading [setuptools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools).

Answer (score 0):

I posted a comment there, still need to document isntallation, for those who don't know composer.
It's a CSV importer, if you know PHP you can add more input formats in the parser class family.
https://github.com/juanmf/RedmineIssueImporter

Basically you define the csv field to Issue field mapping in the yml and run the script.